# How fix hibernate.cfg.xml to MS SQL 2008 connect?

Tags: nhibernate

Work correct with MS SQL 2005. How rewrite file to MS SQL 2008????

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
      <session-factory>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>    
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>    
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,XXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried, and what your specific problem was with the approach?

Answer (score 1):

For the connection string part there is nothing to change ( a part the fact of pointing the correct server). You can change the dialect to `MsSql2008Dialect`, but the 2005 dialect would work too against the 2008.